# Inductive Braking System

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

In a traditional braking system, brake pads produce friction with the brake rotor to slow or stop the vehicle. In an inductive Braking System induction is used to extract energy and act as a  brake. The design of brake rotor is like a rotor slots of a motor that are not skewed. Main reason why rotor slots are skewed is to prevent motor locking. And it is our main reason that braking rotor of Inductive Braking System is not skewed is because it will serve as brake. It works when the pedal is press, the voltage is applied to the braking pad (designed like stator of motor) and it creates a magnetic friction between the pad and the rotor. what are the possible applications of this braking system?

Comment: So it's essentially an eddy current brake with a variable field?  The possible applications will depend immensely on the peak and continuous power dissipation, size, mass, cost, technical risk, environmental compatibility (shock/vibe/temp/water/EMC), etc.  I think we need to know a lot more about the system under discussion.

Comment: For probably the 1st time ever I'm voting to close this question. Your task is to improve it before 4 other people agree with me. If it does get closed you can modify it and then re-ask it. As it stands the complete answer is as I  gave below AND it's not a very useful one to anyone - not you or anyine else.

Comment: A major reason for slot skewing is to reduce drive noise.

Comment: But it's reason too for slot skewing is to prevent motor locking.

Comment: EMI = Electro Magnetic Interference. Inductive based barking systems are know variously as KERS (Kinetic Energy Recovery Systems) Regenerative braking or others.

Comment: Voting to close - there are so many gaps in knowledge represented by this question, that I can't find the fabric.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Actually, closed questions that are edited get automatically placed in the reopen review queue: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen . The point of closing the question is to stop the downvotes/answers until the question is in an answerable state. More changes in the future to emphasize that are coming.

Comment: @Russell - I used to have the same view, but I now vote to close questions quite regularly, my logic is it simply speeds the process of ending up with an answerable question. It seems a question like this almost never survives the first time round. Related - see my meta post [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/should-we-have-a-pop-up-or-dialog-for-new-users-to-remind-them-to-add-basic-info), your views would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- > what are the possible applications of this braking system?

  1. Any rotary motion system that needs a brake.
  2. Any non-rotary motion system that needs a brake and that can drive a rotary motion system (eg rack & pinion etc)

ie What sort of answer better than that one are you wanting?

Comment: Any rotary motion that needs a brake will do. This proposal will be accepted if we can give an application using this system. any suggestion of application?

Comment: @allena. Presumably you will do _some_ of the work towards getting a "proposal" to be accepted? Or is posting vague and technically unsound questions on a web site precisely the effort you think is required?

Comment: Not just rotary motion. These kind of brakes are often used on those 'Drop Tower' fairground rides. At the bottom an aluminium plate slots through a magnet, removing most of the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used as a regenerative brake on amusement park rides, locomotives, cable cars, electric mopeds...